# El espacio en el reciclerview entre producto y prodcuto es muy grande(tanto que he de hacer scroll para ver otro)

Tags: android-studio, base-de-datos

El ejercicio es una base de dao DAO de una lista de la compra y tinee un reciclerView. el problema es qu enetre producto y producto el espacio es enorme
este es el xml principal

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titulo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/titulo"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titulo" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Este el de la fila (he probado a poner el layaout en vertical y en relative y nada)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvProducto"
        android:layout_width="181dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCantidad"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="33dp"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Esta es la clase principal

```
public class ListaCompraFragment extends Fragment {

private ListaCompraViewModel listaCompraViewModel;
private RecyclerView rv;
private AdaptadorProducto adaptador;
private List<Producto> datos = new ArrayList<>();
private Context contexto;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    contexto = this.getActivity();
    listaCompraViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ListaCompraViewModel.class);
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listacompra, container, false);
    rv = root.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.titulo);

    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
    adaptador = new AdaptadorProducto(contexto, datos);
    rv.setAdapter(adaptador);
    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(contexto, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    registerForContextMenu(rv);
    listaCompraViewModel.getProductos().observe(this, adaptador::setDatos);
    return root;
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int posicion = -1;
    try {
        posicion = adaptador.getPosicion();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.mi1:
            Snackbar.make(this.rv, "Se ha elegido borrar el elemento " + posicion, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            Producto p = adaptador.getDatos().get(posicion);
            new borrarProducto(BaseDatosApp.getInstance(contexto)).execute(p);
            break;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

class borrarProducto extends AsyncTask {
    private final BaseDatosApp database;

```
public borrarProducto(BaseDatosApp database) {
    this.database = database;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(final Producto... params) {
    database.productoDAO().delete(params[0]);
    return null;
}
```

y Esta

```
public class ListaCompraViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
private final LiveData<List<Producto>> productos;
public ListaCompraViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    productos = BaseDatosApp
            .getInstance(application)
            .productoDAO().getAll();
}
public LiveData<List<Producto>> getProductos() {
    return productos;
}
```

Comment: Prueba a cambiar en el layout de cada elemento del recycler, el layout de las lineas que has publicado, para el `LinearLayout` `android:layout_height="match_parent"` por `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`.

Comment: justo es eso muchas gracias